# How to render content on top of Electron.js mainwindow page while avoiding webview or browserview

Tags: javascript, html, webview, electron

Let's say you start your electron desktop application like any other application:

```
//main.js
const {app, BrowserWindow, BrowserView, } = require('electron')

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 400,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      webviewTag: true,
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })
mainWindow.loadURL('https://www.google.com')
```

This will open an electron page to Google. I would like now, when the user hovers at the top to render a bar/navbar with buttons. How can I do this when using specifically [BrowserWindow](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#browserwindowsetbrowserviewbrowserview) (**no [webview](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag#webview-tag)**) ?

[image]

**Solutions that I rejected**

Solution 1:

I could simply avoid `mainWindow.loadURL('https://www.google.com')` and use an .html page with `<webview src="https://www.google.com/"></webview>` and code the bar at the top. The reason I avoid [webview](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag#webview-tag) is because according to Electron "is undergoing dramatic architectural changes. This impacts the stability of webviews". In fact, I had problems using webview as the content would sometime not render at all.

Solution 2:

I could use [BrowserView](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-view#class-browserview) to generate the "web page". In fact, I like this solution but I don't get full results with it and I think it's still experimental and this may be the reason.

```
  const view = new BrowserView()
  mainWindow.setBrowserView(view)
  view.setBounds({ x: 0, y: 15, width: 800, height: 525 })
  view.setAutoResize({width: true, height: true})
  view.webContents.loadURL('https://google.com')
```

I would place the BrowserView at Y:15 and keep the top place for the content that appears on top (from the .html page). The only reason I did not find this solution ideal is because:

1. Whenever the BrowserView is used to navigate something that can be watched in fullscreen (e.g YouTube , TikTok videos, etc.), it leaves white bars at the bottom and top (remember the Y set to 15)

This is a fullscreen video example using BrowserView:
[image]
Notice both white bars that don't get covered in full by the fullscreen.

For solution #2 I considered resizing content when it enters in full-screen but with no results.

```
view.webContents.on('enter-html-full-screen', function(){
     view.setBounds({ x: 0, y: 0 }) // set y to 0 to remove the top bar in fullscreen
    /// generates an error instead

})
```

Comment: Currently running into the same issue implementing a titlebar at the top (to make the app more cross platform friendly). Did you resolve this? What was your approach? One approach I tried was a BrowserView overlaying the mainbrowserwindow. This issue with this was that user clicks did not register on the titlebar.

Comment: @Potion I decided to change the design to not use the title bar because it wasn't service a real purpose. Sorry but no solution because I didn't dig deep enough